# Full Height & Width Page?

Tags: html, css

Ok,

So I want to create a website that has full-height and width images with the content on them, and then when you scroll, it scrolls down to the next full-height and width image / part of the site. Put in short, I want each different piece of content on the website to have it's own individual screen, but I want them all on the same page.

I don't have any code to show as I have not yet started, and I have absolutely no clue how it would be done.

Any help that you can give is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you would need high res photos and set them to `background-size: cover;`  keep in mind loading times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [FullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) is what you need. It's a library that helps you get the job done in a more convenient way. For help just take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs).

There are also other libraries that can help you do the same task, also you can do it by creating your own css style, but I think it is much more convenient to use libraries. :D

---

EDIT:

This is the [exact example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/backgrounds.html) that you want to make.

Comment: @CallumWatson, take note what Rafael said that it will make the loading much slower because of high resolution images.